# Does Internet Explorer offer a function to BHOs for downloading files over HTTP?

Tags: c++, winapi, internet-explorer, bho, win32com

A Browser Helper Plugin I'm writing at the moment (C++) needs a list of domains for its work.
This list must be updated weekly and is available as textfile over HTTP.
Does Internet Explorer offer a method to download this file or do I have to use libcurl?
I searched MSDN but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`URLDownloadToFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: This proved helpful to me. I'm actually writing my BHO using C#, though, so I also referred to [this article](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/URLDownloadToFile%20.html) to get me up and running with referencing urlmon.dll and making the call to URLDownloadToFile.